# Removing all files containing a string in their name

Tags: command-line

Is there command line tool that removes everything that `whereis` returns (even if they are directories) but works even with partial names (e. g. if I give the string `gmai` it will also delete files that are named `gmail`).

So recursively look through all directories and delete the contents of those that contain a string in their name.

e. g. If the directories are `mail/gmail/sentmail` delete everything below `gmail`.

Comment: What `whereis` returns is very specific, and normally you wouldn't want to delete the files it lists. It's certainly possible to delete files based on all or part of their names, but I suggest you tell us exactly what you want to do rather than hint at it

Comment: @DavidFoerster I wanted what the answer is doing, except if I am doing this to delete, it might be faster not to look further inside directories that will be deleted

Comment: Unix file systems semantics don't allow the deletion of non-empty directories. Any tool that wants do successfully delete a directory needs to delete all of its children first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can use this [find](/questions/tagged/find) command, but you should test before without the switch `-delete` to test if it's what's you expect :

```
find ./mail -depth -path '*gmai*' -delete
```

It's recursive in all sub-dirs

With the help of comment from @David Foerster and my original command

Answer (score 3):

[`whereis(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/whereis.1.html) doesn't sound suitable to your purpose since it's no general purpose path name search tool.

### *Without* a search index

As Gilles noted in his answer you can use [`find(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/find.1.html) for this job but I want to make a small yet significant improvement<sup>1</sup>:

```sh
find [PATH...] -depth -path '*gmai*' -print # -delete
```

Explanation:

- `find [PATH...]` goes through all files and subdirectories below each `PATH` or the current working directories, if no path was given, and prints all matches (by default).
- `-path PATTERN` matches *full* paths against `PATTERN` using globbing if any, so `*gmai*` matches all path names with an infix `gmai`.
- `-delete` deletes all matched paths (and overrides the default action to print them).
- `-depth` instructs `find` to match children before parents, i. e. directory entries before the parent directories themselves. It's necessary to delete children before their parents because in Unix' file system semantics only empty directories can be deleted.
- `-print` prints all matched paths. Use this to check the result before the actual deletion. Comment in the `-delete` command (by removing the `#` in front of it) to actually delete them.

### *With* a search index

If all the locations that you intend to delete appear in the [`mlocate.db(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/mlocate.db.5.html) search index you can use it for faster searches:

```sh
locate '/your/parent/path/*gmai*'
```

searches all (indexed) paths that start with `/your/parent/path/` and have an infix `gmai` in their remainder. This command only lists search results.

To delete the results use:

```sh
locate -0 '/your/parent/path/*gmai*' | xargs -r -0 -- rm -rf --
```

Explanation:

- `|` redirects the output of the left-side command to the input of the right-side command.
- [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xargs.1.html) collects "items" from its input, appends them to a given command and runs that command.
- `-r` makes `xargs` not run the command if no input item occurs.
- `rm -rf` removes files and directories recursively
- `-0` tells `locate` to delimit matches by null-bytes and `xargs` to accept null-separated input items. This avoids issues with path names that contain white-space and, more specifically, line break characters.

---

<sup>1</sup> that he incorporated in his answer before the question was reopened and allowed me to answer.